# Angular get size of mat-card component

Tags: angular

How to get coordinates and size of `<mat-card>` component?

Maybe question is obvious, but I haven't find answer for a couple of days searching web. Perhaps access to nativeElement will help?

I have app component with "add" button and list of cards.

```js
export class AppComponent {
  id = 0
  public cards = new Array<Card>()

  newCardClick() {
    // todo get sizes and coordinates of all cards
    if (this.cards.length>0)
      console.log(this.cards[0].element.nativeElement)
    this.cards.push(new Card(
      this.id, "Test"+this.id, "", (new Date()).toString(), { x: 10, y: 10+this.id++*85}
    ))
  }
}
```

```scss
button {
    position: fixed;
    bottom:2em;
    right:2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="main__div" #appElement>
  <app-card *ngFor="let card of cards" 
    [card]="card">
  </app-card>
</div>
<button mat-fab color="primary" 
    aria-label="New card" (click)="newCardClick()">
    <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Card component is very simple:

```html
<mat-card #cardElement class="card" 
[cdkDragFreeDragPosition]="card.position"
cdkDrag>
    <mat-card-title>card.header</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>card.description</mat-card-subtitle>
</mat-card>
```

```scss
.mat-card {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(153, 237, 237);
}
```

```js
export class CardComponent implements AfterViewInit{
  @Input() card: Card

  constructor(private element:ElementRef) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.card.element = this.element
  }
}

export class Card{
    constructor(
      public id: number,
      public header: String,
      public description: String,
      public time:String, 
      public position: Point) {
      }
      public element:ElementRef
    }
```

Here is [link](https://github.com/evgenycheryomushkin/stackoverflow-card) to repository with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you are looking for whole code or what,let me give you an example how you can achieve this

To get the coordinates and size of a  component in Angular, you can use the ElementRef and Renderer2 provided by Angular
need to import dependencies in your component file

```
import { Component, ElementRef, Renderer2, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
```

Here it go with your html
Use the @ViewChild

```
<mat-card #cardElement>...</mat-card>
```

use this in component class

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-componentName',
  templateUrl: 'componentName.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['componentName.component.css']
})
export class ComponentName {
  @ViewChild('cardElement', { static: true }) cardElement: ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const cardRect = this.cardElement.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    const cardCoordinates = {
      top: cardRect.top,
      left: cardRect.left,
      width: cardRect.width,
      height: cardRect.height
    };

    console.log('Card coordinates:', cardCoordinates);
  }
}
```

Hope this will help you to get Coordinates.

Comment: Finally I've managed to do it. The idea is to use getBoundingClientRect() in child component itself. In parent component it is not working.